# Understanding simple pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

```
int main()
{
    int *p1,*p2;
    int a;
    p1=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    p2=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    p1=&a;
    p2=p1;
    a=10;
    printf("\n%d\n",*p1);
    printf("\n%d\n",*p2);
    printf("\n%d\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

When I remove the lines `p1=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));` and `p2=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));`
The output doesn't change. Can you please explain why?

Comment: Why should it? What do you think the program is doing?

Comment: unused allocated memory

Comment: I think the pointer will not defined and the output will be garbage

Comment: It is defined, you are defining it in `p1=&a;`. What do you think that line does?

Comment: @Andrei

what you think It does ?

Comment: @AhmedRashad I think it does what it is supposed to do. But we are not here to teach me about pointers. You should reconsider the chain of thought that led you to write that code so that all your misconceptions are cleared.

Comment: @Andrei 
I really asked you to understand what this line dose ?
I did not mean what I understood that I want to teach you.

Comment: @AhmedRashad There are already 4 answers that correctly describe what your program does. Adding my fifth will not make any difference there. What's important, for *you*, is to understand them. Can you write a correct program now?

Comment: @Andrei

yes i can now thanks very much ^_^

Answer (score 10):

```
p1 = &a
```

That just throws away the result of your first malloc line, the first malloc is meaningless.

```
p2 = p1
```

does exactly the same thing for p2.

The space for the POINTERS of p1 and p2 is allocated on the stack, so you can assign to them all you want without additional memory.  You only need the malloc if you want to assign an integer to them that doesn't have its memory allocated somewhere else already.

They are both pointing to memory allocated on the stack for a, and now the memory you've allocated on the heap is leaked and cannot be recovered or released.  You can see this is true because when you set a to 10, all three print lines print 10.

Because of this, the program is only correct WITHOUT those two malloc lines.

Answer (score 1):

The two malloc statements allocate memory for storing two integers and assign their address (pointer) to p1 and p2 respectively. So after the line:

```
p1=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
p2=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

p1 and p2 point to two different memory locations which are just allocated by malloc.

The line:

```
p1=&a;
```

assigns the address of integer a to p1, so p1 no longer points to the newly allocated memory. Instead, it points to integer a.

The line:

```
p2=p1;
```

assign what is in p1 to p2, because p1 contains the address of a, p2 also contains the address of integer a after this line. At this point, p1, p2 both point to integer a.

The line:

```
a=10;
```

assings value 10 to integer a. Because p1 and p2 both point to integer a, the result of *p1, *p2 and integer a should all be 10.

The memory allocated by malloc before causes memory leak as there is no pointer points to them, hence no way to free them. Removing these two lines will not affect the result because after the line:

```
p1=&a;
p2=p1;
```

they become orphaned, leaked memory.

Answer (score 0):

Question: "When I remove the lines p1=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)); and p2=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)); The output doesn't change. Can you please explain why?"

Answer: Because you do not use anymore the memory allocated to p1 and p2 because you assign to p1 the address of a and then you assign to p2 the address now stored in p1

Maybe explained better within the code

```
int main()
{
    int *p1,*p2;                     // define two pointers to int
    int a;                           // define an int variable (space for an int in memory must be reserved)
    p1=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));   // get memory large enough for an int. (int *) makes the default return value of pointer to void a pointer to int
    p2=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));   // same thing but for the other point
    p1=&a;                           // overwrite p1 and puts in it the address used for integer variable a
    p2=p1;                           // overwrite p2 with what p1 has and that is the address of integer variable a
    a=10;                            // now put where the integer variable a has its address the value 10 to
    printf("\n%d\n",*p1);            // output what p1 points to (and it points to address of integer variable a)
    printf("\n%d\n",*p2);            // same for p2
    printf("\n%d\n",a);              // just output a
    return 0;
}
```

tracking with the variables

```
int main()
{
    int *p1,*p2;
    int a;                           // &a = 0xDDDDDDDD
    p1=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));   // p1 = 0xAAAAAAAA
    p2=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));   // p2 = 0xAAAAAAAD
    p1=&a;                           // p1 = 0xDDDDDDDD 
    p2=p1;                           // p2 = 0xDDDDDDDD 
    a=10;                            // a=10 (at address 0xDDDDDDDD)
    printf("\n%d\n",*p1);            
    printf("\n%d\n",*p2);
    printf("\n%d\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

One additional note on how the address for how `a` got its address. This is an automatic variable that gets created when the function is entered and discarded upon exit. So although `a` is only declared and nothing is assigned yet memory is allocated for it.

Quote from K&R Appendix A

> A4.1 Storage Class
>
> .. Automatic objects are local to a block and are discarded on exit from the block. Declarations within a block create automatic objects ...

Comment: @Ahmed Rashad: To be honest I asked myself where `a` got its address from and that is why I kept on looking into this. I made another edit to clarify this point. Any other questions?

Answer (score 0):

- When I remove the lines p1=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)); and p2=(int
  *)malloc(sizeof(int)); The output doesn't change. Can you please explain why?

xaxxon already gave right answer, but here my alternative explanation.

Assume that p1 and p2 are not pointers. Then your code looks like this:

```
int p1,p2;
int a;
p1=6354; // some number (because malloc returns some number)
p2=6376; // some number
p1=a;
p2=p1;
```

If you remove lines

```
p1=6354; // some number
p2=6376; // some number
```

output doesn't change.